# Wrapping multicolumn in tabu

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabu, multicolumn

How do I get the text within a multicolumn to wrap when using `tabu`?  I am hoping that `tabu` makes it somewhat easier than having to specify `p` with a manual specification of the width `\multicolumn{2}{p...}{...}` since one of the main reasons I am using `tabu` is to get the tables set more automatically but my reading of the `tabu` manual and my trial and error attempts and not been successful.

Here is an obviously wrong attempt since `c` does not wrap but at least it gets some code out that could be modified:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabu} to\linewidth{|X|X|X|}
\tabucline-
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ 1 aaaaaaaaa 2 aaaaaaaaa 3 aaaaaaaaa 4 aaaaaaaaa 5 aaaaaaaaa 6
    aaaaaaaaa 7 aaaaaaaaa 8 aaaaaaaaa 9 aaaaaaaaa}&Feb\\ 
Mar&Apr&May\\ 
\tabucline-
\tabuphantomline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

which gives this output:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

You can use a `p` column of the width calculated. In `tabularx` it would be `\TX@col@width` but in `tabu` it seems to be called `\tabucolX`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabu} to\linewidth{|X|X|X|}
\tabucline-
\multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 2\tabucolX+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{1 aaaaaaaaa 2 aaaaaaaaa 3 aaaaaaaaa 4 aaaaaaaaa 5 aaaaaaaaa 6 aaaaaaaaa 7 aaaaaaaaa 8 aaaaaaaaa 9 aaaaaaaaa}&Feb\\ 
Mar&Apr&May\\ 
\tabucline-
\tabuphantomline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How would I also include a third column that is positioned right (`\begin{tabu} to \linewidth {XXr}`)? *Edit:* Looks like I can just use `\multicolumn{3}{p{\linewidth}}{...}`.